# Roslyn - CSharpCompilation to CSharpCompilation reference

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to include an already existing CSharpCompilation object into a new CSharpCompilation object. Similar to project-to-project references in c#.
My current solution is to include the syntax trees of the first compilation in the new compilation, but that gives problems when I need to compare Symbols in both compilations (they are not the same).
MetadataReference.CreateFrom...(), doesn't contain an overload for Compilation.
Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [the `CompilationReference` type](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common/2.0.0/netstandard1.3/doc/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CompilationReference), which can be created by calling [`CSharpCompilation.ToMetadataReference()`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/2.0.0/netstandard1.3/doc/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation/ToMetadataReference(System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray(System.String),System.Boolean)).

Comment: This is what I need, but still new symbols are created for the new compilation, instead of reusing the symbols in the referenced compilation. To find the find the symbol in the first compilation, I need to use SymbolFinder.FindSimilarSymbols(), which I would like to avoid for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put both `Compilation`s' `Project`s in the same `Solution`, then add a [`ProjectReference`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/ProjectReference.cs).

Comment: This will create all symbols only once?

Comment: @TWT: Yes.  This is exactly what VS does when you add a project reference.